# print javascript results into div tag

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been able to make this work as it adds into `<div></div>` tags now I want to remove this array numbers 0,1,2,3 and feed the data into `<div></div>` tags in HTML, How can this be done, How do I make it insert  inside the div tags

```
   <html>
<head></head>
<title>Js test</title>
<h1>Js Test</h2>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = new Array();
function addElement(){
    data.push(document.getElementById('ins_name').value);
    data.push(document.getElementById('gpa').value);
    data.push(document.getElementById('da').value);

    document.getElementById('ins_name').value='';
    document.getElementById('gpa').value='';
    document.getElementById('da').value='';

    display();
}

function display(){
    var str = '';
    for (i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
        //str+="<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td></tr>";
        "<tr>
            <td align=center width=176>Institution </td>
            <td align=center>GPA</td>
            <td align=center width=187>Degree Awarded</td>
        </tr>"

        "<tr>
            <td align=center width=176>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align=center>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align=center width=187>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>"
    }

    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = str;

}
</script>
<form name="jamestown" id="jamestown" method="post" action="samris.php" />
Institution : <input type="text" name="ins_name" id="ins_name" /></br>
GPA : <input type="text" name="gpa" id="gpa" /></br>
Degree Awarded : <input type="text" name="da" id="da" /></br>
</p>
<input type="button" name="btn_test" id="btn_test" value="Button Add Test" onClick='addElement()'; /></br>
</form>
<div id=display></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `str+= "<div>" + data[i] + "</div>";`

Comment: @user3297291, Thanks works fine, i am very grateful now suppose i want to put in <td><</td> Tables how do i present it..

Comment: Try to first write the static HTML that looks the way you want it. Then define which parts of it are "dynamic" and should be added/removed/changed. Eventually, you might want to look into a framework like react, vue, angular or knockout if you're constructing large parts of your UI dynamically. But in this example, you should be able to compose most of your HTML strings similar to my initial comment. E.g.: `"<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td></tr>"`

Comment: Thanks Exactly what i needed. Problem Solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've been adding more and more requirements in the comments, the `innerHTML += ""` approach stops working.

I advice you to create elements using `document.createElement` and add them to your document using `Node.appendChild`.

It's not really an answer to the initial question, but I figured it helps you more than continuing conversation in the comments. Maybe you can edit your question to reflect the additional requirements.

Let me know if there's stuff I used that you don't yet understand. Happy to elaborate!

```js
var inputIds = ["ins_name", "gpa", "da"];
var inputElements = inputIds.map(getById);
var tbody = getById("display");

// Create a new row with cells, clear the inputs and add to tbody
function addRow() {
  // Create a row element <tr></tr>
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  
  inputElements.forEach(function(input) {
    // For each input, create a cell
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    
    // Add the value of the input to the cell
    td.textContent = input.value;
    
    // Add the cell to the row
    row.appendChild(td);
    
    // Clear the input value
    input.value = "";
  });
  
  // Add the new row to the table body
  tbody.appendChild(row);
}

getById("btn_test").addEventListener("click", addRow);

// I added this function because document.getElementById is a bit too long to type and doesnt work with `map` without binding to document
function getById(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

```html
Institution : <input type="text" name="ins_name" id="ins_name" /><br>
GPA : <input type="text" name="gpa" id="gpa" /><br>
Degree Awarded : <input type="text" name="da" id="da" /><br>

<input type="button" id="btn_test" name="btn_test" value="Add Test"/><br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Institution</th>
      <th>GPA</th>
      <th>Degree</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody id="display">
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i have editted the question, Now look at the code again.